# AC out to DC output 90 amp flux core wire welder

Tags: microcontroller, power, capacitor

As stated above I have a welder that I wanted to change from AC output to DC output. I got a 150 amp 3 phase rectifier and two 82000mF capacitors. I hooked the capacitors together in parallel then the two capacitors and rectifier in parallel. I wanted the electrode (i.e. gun, wand) to be negative and the ground clamp to be positive so I hooked them up accordingly. I got everything together and turned it on. The wire feed motor was running sluggish and then I heard a couple of popping noises and and a bubbling sound. The capacitors are blown. I want to know if capacitors that blew in that type of circuit can destroy a rectifier because now the wire feed motor works, but there is no electricity flow through the gun or the ground clamp.
Also since my capacitors are blown does anyone know of a good electrical parts supplier that sells large capacitors.

Comment: What ripple current rating were the capacitors?

Comment: 82000 mF = 82 F. Are you sure you don't mean microfarad (µF) instead of millifarad?

Comment: YOu should never expect any cap to take rectified current up to 150A without a soft start design and choose parts capable of designed ripple current. What were your design specs and how did you not achieve this?

Comment: ALS80A823MF063 can only handle 25A rms at 10KHz  what is your arc resonant frequency?  ALS70A104NS100  can handle 32~35A ripple current.

Comment: ALS70A334QS063 can handle 42A  but what is your max arc cap voltage

Comment: But this is an inexpensive cap https://www.ebay.com/p/Comeaux-Caps-Reversible-Welding-Cap-Gray-Flames-Size-8/1363509196?iid=261350807649&var=560255003019

Comment: Brian Drummond, I dont know the ripple current rating. the only thing on the capacitors is 82000 mF and 6.8SV which I could not find anything on the internet about.

Comment: Transistor- microfarad is what I meant. I dont know how to use the keyboard with different symbols on this computer.

Comment: Tony Stewart- what is a soft start design?

Comment: Tony Stewart- I knew I needed at least a 150 amp rectifier because (stock) the peak output of this machine is 60V at 120 amps. The duty cycle is 20% at 90 amps.

Comment: 6.3 VOLT? Those will explode immediately due to overvoltage. Also, 82 F and no clue about the ripple rating is a recepie for disaster/fire/explosion.

Comment: winny- 6.8SV not 6.8V. do you know what SV stands for?

Comment: Also as stated above the capacitors have already blown so Im not concerned with disaster/fire/explosion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want an industrial quality DC welder then you have to think big and high quality for reliability. The quality factors besides higher voltage and higher capacitance are lower ESR.  I^2ESR =Pd is a key factor for self heating and ripple current as well as passive balancing just like batteries.

The source inductance and gapped cores are often used to regulate current with a mechanical dial or electronic current regulated SMPS.  These required different capacitors are are used in xx kW stack particle ioners and high power  wind power converters.

These industrial parts are not commonly stocked at Digikey or mainstream electronic distributors so details specs are needed before hunting.

[image]

Ref:  https://ewi.org/eto/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/Examination-of-Electrolytic-Capacitors-for-Welding-Applications.pdf

Answer (score 1):

You never stated the voltage on the capacitors. My guess is you used one with too low of a voltage reading and/or wrong polarity when you hooked up the Capacitor.  You only needed to use one capacitor with a minimum of 22000uf 45 volt (75 surge) and better to use a Single phase 200a 1600v bridge inverter. You never noted a leak down resistor and if you didn’t have one on it, you need one or it still hold a charge!